# Unable to connect to Management Endpoint after integrating with VNet - Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-virtual-network

We have an API Management instance with VNet configured in internal mode. We have also added custom domains to all endpoints (Developer Portal, Management, SCM and Gateway). While we are able to access the Developer Portal and call the APIs from within the VNet, accessing API Management instance in Azure portal throws the following error.

"Failed to connect to management endpoint at <> for a service deployed in a virtual network...."

Appropriate ports have been opened and control plane IP Addresses have been configured. Any help or information is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> "Failed to connect to management endpoint at <> for a service deployed
> in a virtual network...."

For the above error , based on the [MS DOC](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/api-management-networking-faqs-demystifying-series-ii/ba-p/1502056) the solution is :

> We have to route the management endpoint response traffic directly to
> the internet to avoid response traffic getting dropped by Azure
> Firewall. This would be achieve by adding routes in the route table
> associated with APIM subnet.
> [image]
>
> We have to add user defined routes for the control plane IP address
> with next hop as internet as shown in above picture.
> Here we can find more about  [control plane IP address for the specific region.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet?tabs=stv2#control-plane-ip-addresses)

For more information please refer this Microsoft documentation : [Connect to a virtual network using Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet?tabs=stv2) .

Comment: This did work for me using an internal API Management configuration.  The NSG rules alone were not enough.  In case you are having trouble like I did finding the list of IP by region, here they are:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/virtual-network-reference?tabs=stv2

Comment: In my case it was due to azure apim was down for few minutes and got automatically resolved.

Comment: @gouravm Same!  All of our non-Production Azure APIM instances are deployed using the `Developer` SKU and therefore are apparently subject to random unannounced outages and "inherent downtime during underneath platform upgrades".

Indeed, according to Microsoft, "No SLA is provided for the Developer tier of the API Management Service.": 

https://www.azure.cn/en-us/support/sla/api-management/